# Is it possible in Python to make a set of methods of a class dependent on input of constructor?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I am reading this [Genshi Tutorial](http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/GenshiTutorial) and see there the following example:

```
from formencode import Schema, validators

class LinkForm(Schema):
    username = validators.UnicodeString(not_empty=True)
    url = validators.URL(not_empty=True, add_http=True, check_exists=False)
    title = validators.UnicodeString(not_empty=True)
```

As far as I understand this example, we create a new class that inherits `Schema` class and this class contain three methods: `username`, `url`, `title`. However, I am not sure about the last because before I only saw methods created with `def`.

Anyway, my question is not about that. I would like to know if it is possible to make the definition of the class dynamic. For example, sometimes I do not want `url` or `title` to be in the class. It seems to be doable (I just use `if` and assign a value to url only if-statement is satisfied.

But what if I do not know in advance what fields I would like to have in the form? For example, now I have username, url and title. But what if later I would like to have `city` or `age`. Can I do something like that:

```
from formencode import Schema, validators

class LinkForm(Schema):

    __init__(self, fields):
          for field in fields:
               condition = fields[field]
               field = validators.UnicodeString(condition)
```

I think it will not work. Is there a work around in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add methods to an instance dynamically. No, you can't do what you want.

You can bind *methods* to the instance in the initializer. Unfortunately what you have there are [**descriptors**](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) and those *must* be bound to the class.

Comment: OK. It probably means that number and names of the descriptors has to be fixed. But cam I, at least, manipulate the right hand side of the assignment operator. In other words, let's say I always have `field_1` descriptor but to what it is assigned depends on the arguments of the constructor. Is it possible?

Comment: I personally feel that an instance initialzer should not affect the class that grossly. I mean, it *can*, but it probably *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 1):

I would go the other way round—first define *all* form fields that might be used, and delete unneeded ones later.

Provided that you have:

```
from formencode import Schema, validators

class LinkForm(Schema):
    username = validators.UnicodeString(not_empty=True)
    url = validators.URL(not_empty=True, add_http=True, check_exists=False)
    title = validators.UnicodeString(not_empty=True)
```

you could do either this:

```
def xy():
    my_form = LinkForm()
    del my_form.url
    …
```

… or this:

```
def xy():
    class CustomLinkForm(LinkForm):
        pass
    if …:
        del CustomLinkForm.url
    …
```

Disclaimer: I am not familiar with FormEncode, so it might depend on its inner workings which of these two versions actually works.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to have a general code. It means that I do not know in advance what fields I might have in the form. So, there could be millions of potential names.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can have a constructor with some arguments after `self` and these arguments will be the value for some members of your class if you have for instance

```
__init__(self, fields):
          self.fields = []
          for field in fields:
               self.fields = self.fields + field
```

see this in [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html)

```
class FileInfo(UserDict):
    "store file metadata"               
    def __init__(self, filename=None): 
         UserDict.__init__(self)      
         self["name"] = filename
```

> 1. Classes can (and should) have doc strings too, just like modules and
>      functions.
> 2. **init** is called immediately after an instance of the
>      class is created. It would be tempting but incorrect to call this the
>      constructor of the class. It's tempting, because it looks like a
>      constructor (by convention, **init** is the first method defined for
>      the class), acts like one (it's the first piece of code executed in a
>      newly created instance of the class), and even sounds like one (“init”
>      certainly suggests a constructor-ish nature). Incorrect, because the
>      object has already been constructed by the time **init** is called,
>      and you already have a valid reference to the new instance of the
>      class. But **init** is the closest thing you're going to get to a
>      constructor in Python, and it fills much the same role.
> 3. The first
>      argument of every class method, including **init**, is always a
>      reference to the current instance of the class. By convention, this
>      argument is always named self. In the **init** method, self refers to
>      the newly created object; in other class methods, it refers to the
>      instance whose method was called. Although you need to specify self
>      explicitly when defining the method, you do not specify it when
>      calling the method; Python will add it for you automatically.
> 4. **init** methods can take any number of arguments, and just like
>      functions, the arguments can be defined with default values, making
>      them optional to the caller. In this case, filename has a default
>      value of None, which is the Python null value.

Note that in the later example you learn how to deal with inherited class, calling `__init()__` for this inherited class.

To answer your not-a-question about class or instance variables, [see this](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class)

> Variables defined in the class definition are class variables; they
>   are shared by all instances. To create instance variables, they can be
>   set in a method with self.name = value. Both class and instance
>   variables are accessible through the notation “self.name”, and an
>   instance variable hides a class variable with the same name when
>   accessed in this way. Class variables can be used as defaults for
>   instance variables, but using mutable values there can lead to
>   unexpected results. For new-style classes, descriptors can be used to
>   create instance variables with different implementation details.